# Displaying user name iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Im using parse and im trying to display the PFUser Name in the subtitle in my tableview. When i try to display like in the code below it crashes my program.

Saving the PFObject:

```
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
    [quoteNew setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"Text"];
```

Querying for the user:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"New";
       // self.className2 = @"Story";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"title";

        self.User = @"user";
       // self.textKey2 = @"title";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
       // self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Trying to display the user:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    // If you want a custom cell, create a new subclass of PFTableViewCell, set the cell identifier in IB, then change this string to match
    // You can access any IBOutlets declared in the .h file from here and set the values accordingly
    // "Cell" is the default cell identifier in a new Master-Detail Project
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.User];

    //cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:self.imageKey];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You'll need to post more code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method or from wherever you initialize "object."

Comment: I see the update, but where are you getting object from?

Comment: `0x1792e4:  b      0x1792c0                  ; __40-[PFTask thenCallBackOnMainThreadAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 340 at PFTask.m:329` @Larme

Comment: Its a signal SIGABRT @Larme

Comment: `PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];` @LyndseyScott This?

Comment: Oh, never mind... I see you're using Parse's tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:

Comment: Do you see what I'm doing wrong? @LyndseyScott

Comment: Not sure yet, but looking through the docs... Do you have a "queryForTable" method?

Comment: No, I use `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`

Comment: But you need to query the object or else the table has no way to know which objects you're accessing.  They have a really good video about this on the Parse website: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-table

Comment: so use the "queryForTable" method? @LyndseyScott

Comment: Do i need this: "queryForTable" method and my method i already have? @LyndseyScott

Comment: Simply write as below - `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"];` Also change objectforkey as per you required columns you want.

Comment: that gets the current user not the one who posted it. @walle84

Comment: Then you would need to check for your query to class User if it's returning you the user you pointing at. Then when you get result as excepted then passing won't be much of prob.